# Is it possible to receive data from window.postMessage inside pdf.js?

Tags: jspdf

I need to send data(API call), from an angular component to an iframe that renders the pdf.js. Can the addEventListener('message') be accessed in the viewer.js file of pdf (or viewer-custom.js)